# Cannot Find File that does exist in IsolatedStorage (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

```
C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{APPID}\Local\shared\transfers\title=null3rd%20Prototype%20feat.%20Meg%20&%20Dia%20-%20Monster%20(Extended%20Mix%20Edit).mp3
```

This is the output from printing the files in the transfers folder as shown below.

```
string root = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
StorageFolder localRoot = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(root + @"\shared\transfers\");

IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files;
files = await localRoot.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery);
for (int l = 0; l < files.Count; l++)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(files[l].Path);
}
```

Then I am trying to move/copy the file to the root folder after the download completes.

Here is the file being moved/copied.

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
if (isoStore.FileExists(App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName))
{
    isoStore.DeleteFile(App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName);
}
try
{
    if (isoStore.FileExists("/shared/transfers/" + App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName))
    {
        isoStore.CopyFile("/shared/transfers/" + App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName, App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

The isoStore.CopyFile() method never executes though because isoStore says the file does not exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store the files into IsolatedStorage, did you make sure that you encoded the file path correctly? It looks like there are spaces in the file path, which may present a problem when reading and writing.

Take a look at the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this before and tried but never actually checked the output. If I encode I get this back, which is incorrect also and wont match. /shared/transfers/title%3dnull3rd+Prototype+feat.+Meg+%26+Dia+-+Monster+(Extended+Mix+Edit).mp3

Comment: Although I don't think that when checking a file path MS would make you encode it yourself, that should be an OS thing.

Comment: Not when encoding it, when you created the file and put it inside IS, was the Url path of that file encoded? You have spaces in your file name which doesn't always work perfectly with Windows. How did you store the file in the first place? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h2ws3ft(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes when I download the file I pass the raw string with spaces unmodified. I guess I'll try changing it to not include any spaces. Edit - you are right. When I download the file and save without spaces it works fine. God damnit Microsoft lol!